# Mapping forsquare data in json in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, foursquare

I am working on extracting data from Foursquare associated with venues (ie: no of photos for each venue, tip count, rating, no of raters, likes, and so on). I have used this code to extract for one venue id which works well on crawling the right data.

```
url3 = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/{}?&client_id={}&client_secret={}&v={}'.format(venue_id908, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, VERSION)
res1 = requests.get(url3).json()
print(res1['response']['venue'].keys())
stats = json_normalize(stats)
```

However, when I try to create a function to retrieve data for a list of venue IDs, I get an error on ['venue']. This is the function that I used:

```
def getvenuesstats(i): 
id_list = []

for i in zip(id_list):
    url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/{}?&client_id={}&client_secret={}&v={}'.format(i, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, VERSION, LIMIT)
    results = requests.get(url).json()
    stats = results['response']['venue']
    id_list.append([(photos_count,
                     tipscount,
                     rating,
                     raters,
                     likes,
                     dislikes,
                     checkins,
                     v['venue']['photos']['count'],
                     v['venue']['stats']['tipCount'],
                     v['venue']['rating'],
                     v['venue']['ratingSignals'],
                     v['venue']['likes']['count'],
                     v['venue']['dislike'],
                     v['venue']['beenHere']['count']) for v in stats             
    ])
stats_venues = pd.DataFrame([item for id_list in id_list for item in id_list])
return(stats_venues)
```

...which returns key error 'venue'.

I would really appreciate your help and I am pretty sure there is an easy way out of this error. I just can't see it. Huge thanks in advance for taking the time to look through my problem and if anything unclear please let me know.

Comment: The required data for some ids might not exist you can print ```i``` before that line to check which id fails.

Comment: NaWeed, thanks. I checked that beforehand. All ids are valid and should get json data for all rows.

Answer (score 0):

You are already subsetting down into `venue` when you define stats.

```
def getvenuesstats(i): 
id_list = []

for i in zip(id_list):
    url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/{}?&client_id={}&client_secret={}&v={}'.format(i, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, VERSION, LIMIT)
    results = requests.get(url).json()
    stats = results['response']['venue']
    id_list.append([(photos_count,
                     tipscount,
                     rating,
                     raters,
                     likes,
                     dislikes,
                     checkins,
                     v['photos']['count'],
                     v['stats']['tipCount'],
                     v['rating'],
                     v['ratingSignals'],
                     v['likes']['count'],
                     v['dislike'],
                     v['beenHere']['count']) for v in stats             
    ])
stats_venues = pd.DataFrame([item for id_list in id_list for item in id_list])
return(stats_venues)
```

Comment: Hi Jacob, Thanks a lot for your answer. It helped solved part of the problem it seems. However, now I get none values all over the id list. still trying all sorts of versions. Thanks though